# How do I pass the JavaScript variable to PHP and Load that PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a requirement to pass the JavaScript object to a PHP file and load that PHP file in browser when a button is clicked.

index.html has the following code:

```
<button id="1a" type="button">Click here</button>
```

custom.js has the following code:

```
var testobject={'element1':1, 'element2':2}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#123456").click(function(event){
        $.post(
            "test.php",
            testobject
        );
    });
```

But I don't know to write a php file to receive this data. Also I am not able to understand how to load this PHP file.

Comment: Hi there. You don't need to use `backticks` to format code lines separately here - just paste in your (indented) code, select it and click the code button. It adds a block format, as per my edit.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first post in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your click event is actually tied to the button using the correct ID, so

```
$("#1a").click(...);
```

in this case. Once you have that, clicking the button will cause a POST to happen to the PHP file, this is where it will load. You can then access those variables in the most simple way like:

```
<?php 
$element1 = $_POST["element1"];
$element2 = $_POST["element2"];
?>
```

as the other answer implies.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I corrected this. But the new php file is not loading in the browser. How to make the php file also to load into the browser along with passing the variables.

Comment: You are making a post to the file, not showing. You are executing the php script behind the scenes, so to say. If you want to show the data you need to do a normal post with a html form, not an ajax call. You could also just pass the raw html data your ajax call returns into a new element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In test.php you can access those variables like so:

```
<?php

$element1 = $_POST["element1"];
$element2 = $_POST["element2"];

echo "data loaded with ajax: " . $element1 . " and " . $element2;
?>
```

you can then manipulate the data and get the info back to the page with the success callback:

```
<div class="ajaxtarget"></div>

$("#1a").click(function(event){ 
   $.post( "test.php", testobject,function(data){
      //here, data is the data returned by test.php
      // if you want to show that content you need a target div to choose where to load it
      $(".ajaxtarget").html(data);
   });
});
```

The same without ajax would be:

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="element1" value="valueyouwant">
    <input type="hidden" name="element2" value="valueyouwantforel2">
    <button id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I used this. But the new php file is not loading in the browser. How to make the php file also to load into the browser along with passing the variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot. for your support. One last question is there any possibility to load this content in a new browser page instead of updating inside a div element?

Comment: Then you don't need ajax at all. i'll update the answer

Comment: Do you have PHP installed on your server? @RamakrishnaKommineni

Comment: You're welcome. consider marking it as the correct answer ;)

Comment: I have installed xampp. It has php.